# Adding a second class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I've been struggling for a few days on this problem and haven't found an adequate solution. Hoping someone can help. What I'm trying to achieve is to allow the user to click "change location", input a location and have that input dictate the background image set for "weather". The problem is that the code works the first time the button is clicked, but not the second. Why could this be?

Here's the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/alexwilson/full/rjagwv/).

I have the following Javascript code:

```
// Dynamic buttons
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
  input = inputs[i];
  input.onmouseover = function() {
    this.setAttribute('data-orig-image', this.getAttribute('src'));
    this.src = this.getAttribute('data-alt-image');
  };
  input.onmouseout = function() {
    this.src = this.getAttribute('data-orig-image');
  };
};

//Get location
var getLocation = $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://ipinfo.io/json",
});

//Once location is received, wrap get weather with returned data/function
getLocation.done(function(data) {
  //Set user's current location 
  var location = data.city;
  //Set user location on page
  $(".location").html(location);
  //Get weather for user's current location
  var getWeather = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='" + location + "&APPID=4b3ff62e3ed31d05cb44a014d891b7e6",
  });
  //Once received do stuff with data!
  getWeather.done(function(data) {
    var temp = data.main.temp;

    var kelvinDegrees = temp;
    var imperialDegrees = ((kelvinDegrees * (9 / 5)) - 459.67);
    var truncatedImperial = Math.floor(imperialDegrees * 100) / 100;
    var metricDegrees = kelvinDegrees - 273.15;
    var truncatedMetric = Math.floor(metricDegrees * 100) / 100;

    $(".degrees").html(truncatedImperial);

    var shown = 1;
    $(".changeUnits").click(function() {

      if (shown == 1) {
        $("#fahrenheit").css("display", "none");
        $("#celsius").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".degrees").html(truncatedMetric);
        shown = 2;

      } else {
        $("#celsius").css("display", "none");
        $("#fahrenheit").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".degrees").html(truncatedImperial);
        shown = 1;
      }
    });

    if (kelvinDegrees > 291.48) {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-hot');
    } else if (kelvinDegrees < 291.48 && kelvinDegrees > 269.26) {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-temperate');
    } else {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-cold');
    }

  });

});

// Get user defined location on click/prompt here
$(".changeLocation").on("click", function() {
  //Define new location via prompt
  var newLocation = prompt("Enter your destination, please:");
  //Set new location on the page
  $(".location").html(newLocation);
  //Get new weather data based on new location
  var getWeather = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q='" + newLocation + "&APPID=4b3ff62e3ed31d05cb44a014d891b7e6",
  });
  // Once received - repeat previous process to set new background image, etc
  getWeather.done(function(data) {

    temp = data.main.temp;

    var kelvinDegrees = temp;
    var imperialDegrees = ((kelvinDegrees * (9 / 5)) - 459.67);
    var truncatedImperial = Math.floor(imperialDegrees * 100) / 100;
    var metricDegrees = kelvinDegrees - 273.15;
    var truncatedMetric = Math.floor(metricDegrees * 100) / 100;

    $(".degrees").html(truncatedImperial);

    var shown = 1;
    $(".changeUnits").click(function() {

      if (shown == 1) {
        $("#fahrenheit").css("display", "none");
        $("#celsius").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".degrees").html(truncatedMetric);
        shown = 2;

      } else {
        $("#celsius").css("display", "none");
        $("#fahrenheit").css("display", "inline-block");
        $(".degrees").html(truncatedImperial);
        shown = 1;
      }
    });

    if (kelvinDegrees > 291.48) {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-hot');
    } else if (kelvinDegrees < 291.48 && kelvinDegrees > 269.26) {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-temperate');
    } else {
      $('.weather').addClass('weather-cold');
    }
  });
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>

<body>

  <div class="weather">

    <div class="ship">

      <div class="container">

        <div class="eighty"></div>

        <div class="twenty">
          <div class="thirty-2">

            <div class="status">
              Loc: <span class="location"></span><br><br> Temp: <span class="degrees"></span>&#176; <span id='fahrenheit'>F</span>
              <span id='celsius' style='display:none;'>C</span><br><br> Cond:
            </div>
            <div class="thirty-2-2"></div>
            <div class="controls">
              <input type="image" id="buttons" class="changeLocation" src="http://i1079.photobucket.com/albums/w513/spudees/img_0531_31979702762_o_zps3nxo0l9w.png" data-alt-image="http://i1079.photobucket.com/albums/w513/spudees/img_0532_32128262395_o_zpsgqmta3cy.png"
              /><br><br>
              <input type="image" id="buttons" class="changeUnits" src="http://i1079.photobucket.com/albums/w513/spudees/img_0534_31979680392_o_zps5t3o2w7w.png" data-alt-image="http://i1079.photobucket.com/albums/w513/spudees/img_0533_32128259015_o_zpsijybngnw.png"
              />
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

and CSS:

```
html,
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/JquobII5VjA/maxresdefault.jpg");
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.weather-cold {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=416901&d=1451562942");
}

.weather-temperate {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top;
  background-image: url("http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/9/9c/Endor_matte.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20070811234822");
}

.weather-hot {
  min-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100vw;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("https://content.pulse.ea.com/content/starwars-ea-com/en_US/starwars/battlefront/news-articles/the-star-wars-battlefront-planets--creating-tatooine/_jcr_content/featuredImage/renditions/rendition1.img.jpg");
}

.ship {
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/LIWZWHP.png")no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
}

.changeLocation {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.eighty {
  min-height: 82vh;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.twenty {
  min-height: 18vh;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.thirty-2 {
  min-width: 30vw;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.thirty-2-2 {
  width: 6%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.status {
  height: 60%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #0f1817;
  z-index: 200;
  color: #5cc35c;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 2.3vmin;
  text-align: left;
}

.controls {
  height: 80%;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #0f1817;
  z-index: 200;
  color: #5cc35c;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 2.5vmin;
}

#buttons {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto\9;
  /* ie8 */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're after, playing around with your sample it's because you only ever add class, never remove it, so on your second click, you still have the first weather-xyz.

You need to remove the existing class you added or otherwise clear the first class you added, eg.

```
$('.weather').removeClass('weather-hot');
```

Comment: Omg. Prior to posting was attempting to do what you said by selecting 'weather' and performing removeclass. Which of course removed the selector entirely. When I set this up to remove the the weather added classes it worked like a charm. Thank you for your response!